# Should there be an incentive for accepting an answer to a posted question?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

On this site there are a lot of questions and a lot of answers.
There is an incentive to post a correct answer, but very frequently no answer is accepted as being correct.
By default the most up-voted answer rises to the top, but often there are just several answers, none of which are marked correct.

This has probably been discussed previously, but it seems to me there should be an incentive (reputation / badge etc) for accepting a posted answer as correct.

Comment: 2 rep is already awarded when accepting an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation <- Third bullet under "You gain reputation when:"

Comment: Voting is different on meta, especially if the question is tagged with [tag:feature-request] (check on 'help' section above, sorry that I can't give the link due to using app)

Comment: You should think twice before asking questions that can be answered by the help centre: http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There already *is* an incentive to accept an answer:

[2 Points for the asker, 15 for the answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

But the acceptance does not mean "this is the correct answer", but "the OP liked this one best".

Also, a question does not need an accepted answer to be useful, being a good sign-post for a duplicate or having a good answer is completely sufficient, preferably well-upvoted.

You can help by finding (and flagging, you need 3K to vote for closing) duplicates, by providing that answer where it's missing, as well as by upvoting good answers.